# How to convert an English sentence that contains "can't take more than 2" into predicate calculus sentence?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

The example is :
A student can’t take more than 2 courses with the same instructor

Comment: The word _can't_ has a somewhat inexact meaning until you decide exactly what it means. "You can't do that!" "Really? It seems to me that I _am_ doing it."

Comment: What have you translated so far?

Comment: amWhy
∀c∃x∃y∃z∃q(takes(x,y,q)^takes(x,z,q) → ¬takes(x,c,q)) Where c,y,z are courses ; x is student ; q is instructor

Comment: If $C$ is the set of courses, $I$ the instructors, and $f\subset C\times I$ the relation that assigns instructors to courses, then you can say $$\neg\left[ \exists x,y,z\in C, \exists a\in I:((\neg(x= y))\wedge (\neg(x= y))\wedge(\neg(y= z))\wedge((x,a)\in f)\wedge((y,a)\in f)\wedge((z,a)\in f))\right]$$

Comment: Everybody seems to be translating, "No student takes more than $2$ courses from any instructor," which is not what the sentence says.  I would say that the sentence means something like, "It is a rule of the college that no student may take courses from any instructor."  It seems quite possible that some student is taking $3$ courses from a single instructor, in violation of the rules.  Perhaps I'm saying the same thing David K says in his comment.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To say "there can't be more than 2 things" it is sufficient to say "there are not 3 distinct things".

Comment: ∀c∃x∃y∃z∃q(takes(x,y,q)^takes(x,z,q) → ¬takes(x,c,q))
Where c,y,z are courses ; x is student ; q is instructor
Is it correct?